# How can I have keycloak IDP trigger IDP initiated logout in my OIDC client SP

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I have an `oidc` client set up in Keycloak. I am using Keycloak as an IDP. When I hit a logout endpoint in keycloak, I want to trigger logout from my SP.

How do I set this up ?

Comment: Here is the documentation for logout https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#logout

Comment: This is when we are initiating logout from the SP